# How to change default text of dropdown in case of directives and apply required validation on directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Actually I've two Questions. I've created a directive for dropdown so I don't have to re write code.
I've default option which is "Select" but I want to change default option. If its Location's drop down then its text should be "Select Location" and if it is Department then it should be "Select Department" by passing text in directive. 
And the other question is that how can apply validation on a dropdown directive. If I apply it on directives html then it will apply on all dropdown directive. But I want to apply it on some directives.
Here is my code.
dropdown.html

```html
<select name="ngModel" id="ngModel" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="option.Id as option.Name for option in ddmodel">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

dropdown.directive.js

```js
(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.directive('dropdown', dropdown);

    function dropdown() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ddmodel: '=',
                ngModel: '=',
                message: "@",
                id: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: '/App/directives/dropdown.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.isOpened = false;
             
               
            }
        };
    }
})(angular.module("IIU"));
```

Using of directive in my code

```html
  <dropdown message="Select Location" ddmodel="DDCollections.LocationList" id="LocationId" name="LocationId" ng-model="staffContract.LocationId">
                            </dropdown>
```

I can pass message through message attribute. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Code

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.LocationList = [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Location one .. '
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'Location two .. '
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    Name: 'Location three .. '
  }, ];


  $scope.DepartmentList = [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Department one .. '
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'Department two .. '
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    Name: 'Department three .. '
  }, ];
});

app.directive('dropdown', dropdown);

function dropdown() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ddmodel: '=',
      ngModel: '=',
      message: "@",
      id: '@',
      validate:'@',
    },
    template: '<select ng-required="{{ validate }}"  name="ngModel" id="ngModel" ng-model="ngModel"' +
      'ng-options="option.Id as option.Name for option in ddmodel">' +
      '<option value=""> {{ message }} </option>' +
      '</select>',
      
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.isOpened = false;


    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <form >
    <h3>
      dropdown location without error
    </h3>
    <dropdown message="Select Location" ddmodel="LocationList" id="LocationId" name="LocationId" ng-model="LocationId"   validate='true'>
    </dropdown>

    <h3>
      dropdown department with error
    </h3>

    <dropdown message="Select Department" ddmodel="DepartmentList" id="DepartmentId" name="DepartmentId" ng-model="DepartmentId"   validate='false'>
    </dropdown>
      <br>
      <br>
      


      <input type="submit">
      </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my day

Comment: Welcome Haris,  can u able to tick my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

**1 -** To replace the default with the `message` you pass, simply replace the default option text to value of `message` as,

```
<select name="ngModel" id="ngModel" ng-model="ngModel" 
            ng-options="option.Id as option.Name for option in ddmodel">
    <option value=""> {{ message }} </option>
</select>
```

**2 -** To enable errors for specific select, you can pass another variable to indicate to anable or diable the `errors`, based on that variable you can decide to show or hide the `errors` by using something like `ng-if`, as,

```
<!-- show-errors true or false -->
<dropdown message="Select Location" ddmodel="LocationList" 
    id="LocationId" name="LocationId" ng-model="LocationId" show-errors="false">
</dropdown>

.....
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
  ddmodel: '=',
  ngModel: '=',
  message: "@",
  id: '@',
  showErrors: "="
},
.....

<select name="ngModel" id="ngModel" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="option.Id as option.Name for option in ddmodel">
    <option value=""> {{ message }} </option>
</select>
<span ng-if="showErrors">errors</span>
```

here is a simple [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wvsrk6h3/1/)

Comment: your answer # 1 is correct. But in 2nd answer is not which I needed. I want to apply html5's validation. If I use required attribute so it apply on all dropdown. I want to add on some specific dropdowns.